# Add same value to Dictionary for both key and value in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am using a dictionary full of integers and depending on the data I get from another source I just want the Key to be the same as the value. Sometimes 'Value1' is null in the database. If it is null then I just need to use 'Value2' in both the Key and the Value.

```
if (GetFrom.Asset != null)
{
    SomeDictionary.Add(Value2, Value1)
}
else
{
    SomeDictionary.Add(Value2, Value2)
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing the same thing in both the `if` and the `else` clause?

Comment: @Grant: I *think* it's been edited since my comment. I'm pretty sure it was just Value2 everywhere before. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: When I step through it the code I posted it does add the same value and key on the else statement. I had a Console.WriteLine(Value1) in the if statement and not a Console.WriteLine in the else statement.

Comment: @Grant There was actually nothing wrong with the code when I stepped through it, I checked the dictionary values and both Value2,Value2 appear in the else statement. using the ?? is a more efficient way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you have works, you could use the ternary operator to make it a one-liner. It doesn't improve the speed, but could make it slightly more readable (matter of opinion).

```
SomeDictionary.Add(Value2, GetFrom.Asset != null ? Value1 : Value2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
SomeDictionary.Add(Value1 ?? Value2, Value1 ?? Value2);
```